# Is there a way to enable container level network policy in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, apache-kafka, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Currently, network policies in Kubernetes allow you to control egress and ingress on the pod. However, if two containers run in the same pod, there is no way to have distinct network policies for each container.

I am trying to implement a Kafka consumer, which is able to read messages from a broker which is hosted in our private subnet and then dispatch this request to the side container, which runs untrusted code designed by random users on the web. Since there is no way to restrict container communication with a policy, this untrusted code can reach our Kafka broker.

I understand that this can be limited by enabling authentication on Kafka. However, the service would still be exposed to an untrusted container.

Is there any way to stop this from happening? We have explored Kata containers, Istio + Envoy and Cilium, none of which seem to help solve this problem.

Comment: Why not run two separate pods? Or, even a separate namespace, where you actually can control NetworkPolicy resources?

Comment: @OneCricketeer The entire purpose is to use Kafka, and its throughput to process these messages faster. If we were to host this in a separate namespace or pod, then we would have to establish a different networking channel, such as HTTP or GRPC, between Kafka and the untrusted code, which brings its own set of challenges.

Comment: No? You can allow TCP Kafka connection between two pods and/or namespaces. You dont need a layer 7 protocol

Comment: In other words, it's not really clear how else you are interacting with a "sidecar container" without some RPC interaction. But, you really should not be running untrusted code in the same pods as trusted services,  IMO

Comment: The communication would have still occurred with an L7 protocol with the sidecar approach; however, since they are both part of the same pod, I could scale them up simultaneously using an event-driven scaler like Keda without introducing the CNI, DNS discovery systems, etc... But I understand your reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

> this can be limited by enabling authentication on Kafka

You would need to enable asymmetric encryption (SSL / Kerberos) between Kafka and any client. This way, you would delegate public keys to any trusted client, while any untrusted code would be unable to connect without a valid key-pair. Also, the encryption would prevent untrusted code from packet-sniffing the network data local to that container/pod/host. None of this requires/involves Kubernetes.

- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security
- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/encryption.html#encrypt-with-tls

Beyond that, run the untrusted code in the container on a limited-access (non-root) user account, and regular security best practices you should be doing in containers, anyway.

If you need finer network policies in the container, install `iptables`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The container doesn't have root access and doesn't share a kernel either, so that is taken care of. And as mentioned in the original question, we can deny access using various authentication and authorisation approaches in Kafka, and Kerberos can certainly improve it, but none stops us from completely denying access to a particular broker. 

When you say install iptables, do you mean to install IP tables in the container and write DENY rules to a specific IP range?

Comment: Yes. If you need to block network requests from a container, best do that from the container and not allow untrusted code to read/modify those rules

Comment: Otherwise, they can still do a network/port scan and find "oh, something is running on port 9092, let's DOS that machine with invalid requests..."